# Ubuntu partition filesystem not detected after Win 8 install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I installed Windows 8 over an existing dual boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I thought, like all times, a simple grub reinstall would fix the issue. But this time something weird happened.

I ran boot-repair from a liveUSB, rebooted, but still didn't get GRUB. Then I started investigating a bit. Here's fdisk:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   204802047   102297600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       204804094   283410431    39303169    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda4       283410432   976773119   346681344    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       267788288   283410431     7811072   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Windows is in sda2 and Ubuntu in sda3 (ext3). If I try to mount it:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Here's parted -l:

```
Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      106MB   105GB  105GB   primary   ntfs
 3      105GB   145GB  40.2GB  extended
 5      137GB   145GB  7999MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 4      145GB   500GB  355GB   primary   ntfs
```

So I'm not able to detect the file system of my Ubuntu partition!

Here's the boot-repair log: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6221718/

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've got another physical disk, your Windows installation has trashed Linux. I'm afraid that recovering Ubuntu is essentially impossible at this point. If you've got important user data, you might try using [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to try to recover it, but that can be a tedious process. As to getting Ubuntu to boot again, re-installing is the easiest solution by far.